# How second lines of flex consume space above

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am really newbie on flexbox, I am trying to layout webpage using flexbox, really simple, just has navigation bar, side bar and content:

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation {
    background-color: aqua;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}

.side-bar {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-basis: 68px;
}

.content {
    background-color: burlywood;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="navigation">
    </div>
    <div class="side-bar">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</body>
```

and the result I got:

[image]

What I want is side bar and content bar consume space above without height calculation (ex: calc(100% - 60px)) like below:

[image]

Comment: Can you share an image of what you want to get?

Comment: the main disadvantage of `flexbox` comapred to `css-grid` is, that it is only good in controlling either width or height but not both. In you case you need to control both and as such would be better off with `css-grid`.

Comment: @tacoshy: thanks for the comment, I dont know css-grid, so I  guess I have to take a look on grid

Comment: @s.kuznetsov: Sorry, it does not answer my question I tried to avoid calc(100vh - ?)

Comment: @cuongle, Why don't you want to use computation `(100vh - n)`? Also, do you need a footer?

Answer (score 2):

Flex solution:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
}

.a {
   width: 100vw;
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: pink;
}
.b {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
}
.c {
   width: 20vw;
    height: 90vh;
    background-color: red;
}
.d {
    width: 80vw;
    height: 90vh;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='a'></div>
  <div class='b'>
    <div class='c'></div>
    <div class='d'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments: I want to offer you an alternative: CSS-Grid. It however has limited support for IE11 and 13.

with display grid, we declare to columns by using: `grid-template-column: min-content auto;`. That way the left side for the sidebar will consume as much space as you declare on the sidebar and the content all remaining space. To have the navbar span both columns use: `grid-column: span 2;`.

Same story for the rows: top row gets a height of min-content to use the height that you declare for it and the content and sidebar a height of auto to consume all remaining space.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  grid-template-rows: min-content auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: span 2;
  height: 60px;
}

.side-bar {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 68px;
}

.content {
  background-color: burlywood;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navigation">
  </div>
  <div class="side-bar">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you don't need to apply your styles to html and body you may face unwanted result since body will become a grid item of the grid apply to html and will take only one track. Apply to body should be enough

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I just copied the code from OP and adjusted it from flex to grid.